# I put no arguments in the final line, but I get this error: "TypeError: draw() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I tried putting in all applicable arguments, leading to an error saying "thickness is not described"

```
import turtle

class Blocks:
    def __init__(self, color, thickness):
        self.color = color
        self.thickness = thickness
        turtle.color(self.color)
        turtle.width(self.thickness)

    def draw_square():
        for i in range(4):
            turtle.forward(100)
            turtle.right(90)

    def draw_legs():
        ang_lst1 = [45, 135, 225]
        ang_lst2 = [45, 315, 0]
        n = 0
        for i in range(3):
            turtle.forward(100)
            turtle.right(ang_lst1[n])
            turtle.forward(56)
            turtle.right(ang_lst2[n])
            n += 1

    def draw():
        for i in range(2):
            draw_square()
            turtle.goto(-40, 40)
        draw_legs()

red_block = Blocks('red', 5)

red_block.draw()
```

Comment: You need to accept `self`, or make your methods static. All methods (as opposed to functions) are implicitly passed a reference to the object instance they're attached to.

Comment: That is indeed the error you get when you define a method of a class without giving it either the required `self` parameter or using the `@staticmethod` decorator. Please read about how Python classes work: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects